# Stuck on twitch viewer python script

Tags: python, json, pip

I'm using python 2.7.10 with livestreamer, json and request downloaded from pip.
Enviroment: windows 8.1

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json
import sys
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue

numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
builderThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
startTime = time.time()
numberOfSockets = 0
concurrent = 25
urls = []
urlsUsed = []

def getURL(): # Get tokens
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/CHANNEL_NAME", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter

def build(): # Builds a set of tokens, aka viewers
    global numberOfSockets
    global numberOfViewers
    while True:
        if numberOfSockets < numberOfViewers:
            numberOfSockets += 1
            print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
            urls.append(getURL())

def view(): # Opens connections to send views
    global numberOfSockets
    while True:
        url=q.get()
        requests.head(url)
        if (url in urlsUsed):
            urls.remove(url)
            urlsUsed.remove(url)
            numberOfSockets -= 1
        else:
            urlsUsed.append(url)
        q.task_done()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, builderThreads):
        threading.Thread(target = build).start()

    while True:
        while (numberOfViewers != numberOfSockets): # Wait until sockets are         built
            time.sleep(1)

        q=Queue(concurrent*2)
        for i in range(concurrent):
            try:
                t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                t.daemon=True
                t.start()
            except:
                print 'thread error'
        try:
            for url in urls:
                print url
                q.put(url.strip())
                q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(1)
```

It just goes to "did you specify the channel.." returnvalue. 
Hopefully someone a littlebit more awake then me can help me.

Thanks!

## #

Edit:

Feel free to try it, just change "CHANNEL_NAME" with a random channel.

Comment: Does it still works in october 2020?